# FormItem setFieldTitle method

Tags: smartclient

Does `DynamicForm` or `FormItem` have a method to set a field title?

Currently I'm doing something like this

```
var fields = myForm.fields;
fields[0].title = "a brand new title";
myForm.setFields(fields);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer according to Isomorphic on SmartClient Forum

> A valid way to do this would be formItem.setProperty("title",
>   newTitle) and then item.redraw().